# Trying to prevent click through on a SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, grasshopper

Good afternoon folks,

I’m new to the coding game, and have been through Grasshoppers tutorials.

In there sandbox environment, I am trying to code a simple “keep it up” game using SVGs in JavaScript.

I have a background SVG, and a ball SVG.

I have given both of these .on(“click”,...) arguments.

The background SVG resets the ball to a random cX position, and a cY position of 35.

The ball SVG, should transistion the ball back to cY 35, at a random cX, to a cY of 1000 at a random cX.

When the ball is clicked, it clicks through to the background and interrupts the animation and returns it to cY 35 and random cX instantly.

How can I prevent the clickthrough?

I’ve tried random assortments of of tests, but have been unable to make anything work.

Many thanks,
TheShadows645

Edit as requested;
PosistionX is just an array with various numbers to give cX.

```
var ball = svg.append(‘circle’).attr(‘fill’,’white’).attr(‘r’,25).attr(‘cY’,’35).attr(‘cX’, PickRandom(PosistionX));

var background =svg.append(‘rect’).attr(‘fill’,’green’).attr(‘height’,’1000’).attr(‘width’,’1000’).attr(‘cY’,’0’).attr(‘cX’,’0’);

function kickBall () {
ball.on(‘click’, () => {
    ball.transistion().attr(‘cY’,’35’).attr(‘cX’,’PickRandom(PosistionX)).duration(3000);

ball.transistion().attr(‘cY’,’1000’).attr(‘cX’,’PickRandom(PosistionX)).duration(3000);
});
```

Edit 2;

I have increased ball size, and slowed the animations down. I have found that the ball is now not resetting apparently, but is not rising on the first transistion. And instead falling straight to the new PosistionX.

Edit 3; To clarify, it now appears the issue is not a click-through issue, just incredibly poor “hit-box” on the original circle SVG. However, the new .transistion issue is still a problem if anyone has any advice.

Comment: In the ball's on click handler, call `.stopPropagation()` on the event.

Comment: I’m assuming I’m limited by using Grasshopper, as I cannot find a .stopPropagation() under any of the selections possible when referencing either the ball, or the .on event.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve]. Just the two shapes, not the whole game.

Comment: Please add the code that sets up the click event for the ball to your question. You could also check for cY being 35 already when you handle the background click and do nothing in that case.

Comment: See edits, included what I’ve set the ball and background vars as well as the ball.on handler

Comment: Also read about **SVG & pointer events** : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/svg-interaction-pointer-events-property/

Comment: Use `ball.on('click', e => { ... }` instead of `()`, that way you can call `e.stopPropagation()` inside the function.

Comment: Chris G, I apologise if this comes off stupid. Is the e a var I need to create? Is it a string? When creating the .on event, I haven’t got an option for e => {....}, or is this another limitation of grasshopper, and being mobile?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `Event Delegation`. Set an event on the parent of both of your SVGs and then use `e.target` to check from which element is the event happening and accordingly write your logic.

Something like this: (Just telling the logic)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="svg1" id="svg1">SVG1</div>
  <div class="svg2" id="svg2">SVG2</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
   if(event.target.id==="svg1"){
      // SVG1 logic here
   }

   if(event.target.id==="svg2"){
      // SVG2 logic here
   }
});
```

**Note:** So the idea is that once a click happens within the wrapper be it from `svg1` or `svg2`, we first cross check from what element is the event being fired. And for that element set our code as per our requirement. `e.target.id` helps us to know from which element the event is bubbling.

Comment: Hi Imran, a couple of questions re your answer. Is “document” a string? Also, I believe I’m being limited by using grasshopper as .querySelector is available. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi @TheShadow645. **document** is a javascript dom object used to access our elements within DOM. We can say **The document object represents your web page** once loaded in the browser

Comment: Hi, please [do not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) use, recommend or link to w3schools

Comment: Don't send newbies there :) And please remove the comment linking there, a backlink from here benefits them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let background = document.getElementById('background');
let ball = document.getElementById('ball');

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.closest('#background')) {
    ball.style.top = '0px';
    ball.style.left = '0px';
  } else if (e.target.closest('#ball')) {
    ball.style.top = (Math.random() * 100) + 'px';
    ball.style.left = (Math.random() * 100) + 'px';
  }
});
```

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<svg id="background" width="1000" height="1000">
  <rect width="1000" height="1000" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>

<svg id="ball" height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```